# Aplicación Android se detiene al ejecutar esto

Tags: android-studio

tengo un problema y es que al ejecutar el siguiente código la aplicación se me detiene inmediatamente, he probado con poner como comentario una línea del código en concreto, que esta en la línea 46, que es esta; "double valorBruto = Double.parseDouble(bruto);", y no me "crashea", alguien se le ocurre porque?, obviamente también he comentado las otras líneas donde uso  valorBruto ya que sino habría error de sintaxis..

```
   package com.alumno.recupandroidigor;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class Actividad_Principal_igor extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_principal_igor);
        RadioGroup tRadioG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        Button siguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final EditText nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final EditText salarioB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final TextView salarioN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent explicit_intent;//Declaro el Intent.

                //Instanciamos el Intent dandole:
                //el contexto y la clase a la cual dirigir.
                explicit_intent = new Intent(Actividad_Principal_igor.this, Actividad_Nomina_igor.class);
                String auxNombre = nombre.getText().toString();
                String auxSalarioB = salarioB.getText().toString();

                explicit_intent.putExtra("nombre", auxNombre);
                explicit_intent.putExtra("salario_bruto", auxSalarioB);
                startActivity(explicit_intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


        tRadioG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            String bruto = salarioB.getText().toString();
            double valorBruto = Double.parseDouble(bruto);
            double IRPF;
            double NETO;
            double descuento;

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton2) {
                    IRPF = 0.8;


                    descuento = IRPF * valorBruto;

                    NETO = valorBruto - descuento;

                    String resultado = String.valueOf(NETO);
                    salarioN.setText(resultado);
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton) {
                    IRPF = 0.9;

                    descuento = IRPF * valorBruto;

                    NETO = valorBruto - descuento;

                    String resultado = String.valueOf(NETO);
                    salarioN.setText(resultado);
                } else {
                    IRPF = 1;

                    descuento = IRPF * valorBruto;

                    NETO = valorBruto - descuento;

                    String resultado = String.valueOf(NETO);
                    salarioN.setText(resultado);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para futuras preguntas ayudaría que pusieras también el mensaje de error que recibes... Puede que haya algún problema  con esto: `String bruto = salarioB.getText().toString();`, trata de verificar que la variable `bruto` es un valor válido para usar con `parseDouble`. De hecho tu código escrito así no es seguro, porque [el método puede hacer saltar dos `Excepciones`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)): `NPE` si le pasas una cadena nula, y `NFE` si le pasas una cadena que no se puede parsear...

Comment: Hola @Igor como menciona A.Cedano el uso del LogCat es indispensable en Android, el error puede ser al realizar el parseo pero sin embargo deberías especificar mejor tus preguntas, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1º -  Comprueba si se ha realizado correctamente la inicialización del EditText (en este caso es salarioB), aunque eso debería funcionar.

2º - Deberías hacer una comprobación en el `setOnCheckedChangeListener` ya que se está ejecutando por lo que, cuando haces

```
String bruto = salarioB.getText().toString()
```

esto te devuelve un error de `NullPointer` ya que el `salarioB.getText()` no te devuelve nada porque está vacio.

Comment: **Ayúdanos  a mantener la calidad en el sitio**, te sugiero revisar [answer], hay preguntas que tratemos de no responderlas si no esta claro lo que se requiere, en este caso estas dando opciones de validación pero aún esto puede no solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 2):

Es muy importante que al obtener datos directamente de la pantalla hagas validaciones, para evitar errores.

Por ejemplo:

1) Valida si el dato es null o se devuelve vacio.

```
if(K.getText().toString().isEmpty){ //<-- Esto devuelve un booleano
  // Si esta vacío
   }
```

2) Comprueba que el dato es un double 
- Puedes usar el clásico try catch

```
 try {
    //Aqui la validacion
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Si entra aqui significa que el dato no es un número.
}
```

3)Tambien una expreción regular:

```
String decimalPattern = "([0-9]*)\\.([0-9]*)";

String number="20.00";

boolean match = Pattern.matches(decimalPattern, number);
System.out.println(match); //if true then decimal else not
```

Comment: También pudes usar Debug en android studio, esto te permitirá ir linea por linea para encontrar exactamente el error.

Comment: Enlace para usar el debug https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html?hl=es-419

Comment: **Ayúdanos  a mantener la calidad en el sitio**, te sugiero revisar [answer], hay preguntas que tratemos de no responderlas si no esta claro lo que se requiere, en este caso estas dando opciones de validación pero aún esto puede no solucionar el problema.